# Use logical and && and logical or || construct substitute of if/else statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am thinking about if there are just two types of conditions (0, 1), can we use the following code to substitue if/else construct in shell in one line. 
This is first expression I figured out, while it need the condition that op1 won't fail.

```
[ condition ] && op1 || op2
# condition = true then do op1, if op1 success too, then won't execute op2
# condition = false then do op2, won't execute op1, execute op2 directly.
```

So I figure out the second version

```
[ condtion ] && ( op1 || 1 ) || op2
```

What I think is `( op1 || 1 )` will always be true instead of considering op1's result. But I am not sure if it will work correctly? Anyone has more ideas?

Comment: Do you want to execute op1 and op2 if condition is met?

Comment: `( op1 || 1 )` will result in a command not found error if `op1` fails because 1 isn't a valid command unless you defined it somewhere. The bash equivalent is `( op1 || : )` with the `:` being a no-op command that always exits successfully.

Comment: This seems like you're trying to work around the pitfalls related to `A && B || C` listed in the bashFAQ, where switching to if/else syntax would make things much easier. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3

Comment: If you meant `1` to mean `true`, and for some reason don't want to _write_ `true` or its synonym `:`, you can use `((1))` to explicitly enter an arithmetic context in which `1` is true. But... don't. Really. KamilCuk's answer is on-point in every respect, _including_ the advice to use `if` instead. `a && b || c` is not an adequate substitute for `if a; then b; else c; fi`.

Comment: Thank you all your reply guys, I just happened to think about this possible substitution. About if we can combine logical operators to substitute if/else construct completely.

Comment: Also, using `( )` instead of `{ }` has performance impact (and behavioral impact as creating a subshell modifies variable scope), so the advice to use `{ op1 || true; }` instead of `( op1 || true )` is practical, not just aesthetic.

Comment: @norbjd No, if condition met, i hope this expression will just do op1.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for your explaination. But still don't know if there is a possibility these two equal to each other totally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I am not sure if it will work correctly?

No, there is no such command as `1`. You can use `true` or `:`.

Also, `(` will spawn a subshell. Use `{ op1 || :; }`.

> Anyone has more ideas?

Do not write unreadable code that you have to think about how it works and are not sure. Write an `if`. Everyone understands an `if`. It's simple, readable, you know what's going on. Just write an `if`, do not use `&& ||` when you mean an `if`.

```
if [ condtion ]; then op1; else op2; fi
```

---

> hether [ condition ] && {op1 || :;} || op2 equals to if condition; then op1; else op2; fi or not ?

The `if` condition exits with the exit status of last command executed in the body, or if body was not executed, with 0. The `&& ||` will exit with 0.

```
$ true && { false || :; } || false; echo $?
0
$ if true; then false; else false; fi; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am still new to bash, so whether `[ condition ] && {op1 || :;} || op2` equals to `if condition; then op1; else op2; fi` or not ?(I am still not sure, could you explain them in detail?)

Comment: @yupe, note that `{ op1` and `{op1` are two different things -- the space after the `{` is mandatory. But to answer your yes-or-no question: Yes, `[ condition ] && { op1 || :; } || op2` is behaviorally identical to `if [ condition ]; then op1; else op2; fi`, though I wouldn't ever advise using the former in practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your correction and explaination.